# rewrite rule .php to show .html in url add errordocument 404 not work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have in my FTP Folder only .php files like test.php and show the files in Browser with test.html

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

When i now add ErrorDocument 404

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

its shows error document right on
/test
/test.htm

but not in filenotexist.html (all files with .html that not exists on server)

it only stands in the browser: File not found.
this is because of the rewriterule.
Has anybody a solution for this ?

Comment: So what sample URL you are hitting and what error OR info its giving to you in browser?

Comment: browser statuscode ist 404 but the browser not load the errordocument on not exisitng .html files. only shows "File not found.". on /xxx or with other extensions excluded .html it show right the errordocument

Comment: Temporarily remove (or comment out) the mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess`. If you request `filenotexist.php` - does that trigger the `ErrorDocument`?

Comment: filenotexist.php redirects to filenotexist.html and i get the same, 404 site without errorodocument, only "File not found" text.

Comment: Is that with the existing directives removed and browser cache cleared? (301 - permanent - redirects are cached persistently by the browser, which can make testing problematic.) Your existing directives redirect from `.php` to `.html`, but then `.html` is rewritten back to `.php`. I think the problem might be to do with how PHP is implemented on your system.